# Algorithm to find diameter of a tree using BFS/DFS. Why does it work?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, trees, graph-traversal

[This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11263/8660) link provides an algorithm for finding the diameter of an undirected tree **using BFS/DFS**. Summarizing:

> Run BFS on any node s in the graph, remembering the node u discovered last. Run BFS from u remembering the node v discovered last. d(u,v) is the diameter of the tree.

Why does it work ?

Page 2 of [this](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/fall01/handouts/ps9sol.pdf) provides a reasoning, but it is confusing. I am quoting the initial portion of the proof:

> Run BFS on any node s in the graph, remembering the node u discovered last. Run BFS from u remembering the node v discovered last. d(u,v) is the diameter of the tree.
>
> Correctness: Let a and b be any two nodes such that d(a,b) is the diameter of the tree. There is a unique path from a to b. Let t be the first node on that path discovered by BFS. If the paths $p_1$ from s to u and $p_2$ from a to b do not share edges, then the path from t to u includes s. So
>
> $d(t,u) \ge d(s,u)$
>
> $d(t,u) \ge d(s,a)$
>
> ....(more inequalities follow ..)

[image]

The inequalities do not make sense to me.

Comment: I don't find the quote in the linked question.

Comment: Try replacing "do not share edges" with "do not share vertices" in the solution.

Comment: You are using only BFS, not DFS.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the same method works with two DFSs, and instead of choosing $u$ to be the vertex discovered last, choose $u$ to be a vertex with maximal depth in the depth-first tree.

Answer (score 14):

All parts of proving the claim hinge on 2 crucial properties of trees with undirected edges:

- 1-connectedness (ie. between any 2 nodes in a tree there is exactly one path)
- any node can serve as the root of the tree.

Choose an arbitrary tree node $s$. Assume $u, v \in V(G)$ are nodes with $d(u,v) = diam(G)$. Assume further that the algorithm finds a node $x$ starting at $s$ first, some node $y$ starting at $x$ next. wlog $d(s,u) \geq d(s,v)$. note that $d(s,x) \geq d(s,y)$ must hold, unless the algorithm's first stage wouldn't end up at $x$. We will see that $d(x,y) = d(u,v)$.

The most general configuration of all nodes involved can be seen in the following pseudo-graphics ( possibly $s = z_{uv}$ or $s = z_{xy}$ or both ):

```
(u)                                            (x)
  \                                            /
   \                                          /
    \                                        /
     ( z_uv )---------( s )----------( z_xy )
    /                                        \
   /                                          \
  /                                            \
(v)                                            (y)
```

we know that:

1. $d(z_{uv},y) \leq d(z_{uv},v)$. otherwise $d(u,v) < diam(G)$ contradicting the assumption.
2. $d(z_{uv},x) \leq d(z_{uv},u)$. otherwise $d(u,v) < diam(G)$ contradicting the assumption.
3. $d(s,z_{xy}) + d(z_{xy},x) \geq d(s,z_{uv}) + d(z_{uv},u)$, otherwise stage 1 of the algorithm wouldn't have stopped at $x$.
4. $d(z_{xy},y) \geq d(v,z_{uv}) + d(z_{uv},z_{xy})$, otherwise stage 2 of the algorithm wouldn't have stopped at $y$.

1) and 2) imply $\, \\ d(u,v) = d(z_{uv},v) + d(z_{uv},u) \\ \qquad\geq d(z_{uv},x) + d(z_{uv},y) = d(x,y) + 2\, d(z_{uv}, z_{xy}) \\ \qquad\qquad\geq d(x,y)$.

3) and 4) imply $\, \\ d(z_{xy},y) + d(s,z_{xy}) + d(z_{xy},x) \\ \qquad\geq d(s,z_{uv}) + d(z_{uv},u) + d(v,z_{uv}) + d(z_{uv},z_{xy}) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\ \, $ equivalent to $\, \\ d(x,y) = d(z_{xy},y) + d(z_{xy},x) \\ \qquad\geq 2*\,d(s,z_{uv}) + d(v,z_{uv}) + d(u,z_{uv}) \\ \qquad\qquad\geq d(u,v)$.

therefore $d(u,v) = d(x,y)$.

analogue proofs hold for the alternative configurations

```
                 (u)                          (x)
                   \                          /
                    \                        /
                     \                      /
     ( s )---------( z_uv )----------( z_xy )
                     /                      \
                    /                        \
                   /                          \
                 (v)                          (y)
```

and

```
                          (x)        (u)  
                          /            \  
                         /              \ 
                        /                \
     ( s )---------( z_xy )----------( z_uv )
                        \                /          
                         \              /           
                          \            /            
                          (y)        (v)
```

these are all possible configurations. in particular, $x \not\in path(s,u), x \not\in path(s,v)$ due to the result of stage 1 of the algorithm and $y \not\in path(x,u), y \not\in path(x,v)$ due to stage 2.

Comment: (1) Regarding the first graphic, shouldn't the path from s to x always contain vertices u and v in some order since they are present on tree generated by BFS? (2) Could you clarify how the inequalities are obtained ? (3) Since the BFS starting from s and that starting from x contain u,v somewhere on the path, I believe the graphic should be as shown in the link http://imgur.com/jQ94erY . How does the reasoning you provided apply here ?

Comment: @curryage note that the tree is given and not being constructed by the bfs! specific answers: ad 1) no. imagine a refinement of the tree in graphics (1) by adding arbitrarily many nodes on the edge $(s, z_{xy})$ and exactly 1 node on the edge $(z_{xy}, x)$. the first stage bfs will then end at x. ad 2) which inequality/ies are unclear? we are always assuming that $(u,v)$ be a path the length of the graph's diameter $diag(G)$. this is well defined as G is 1-connected. ad 3) no: 3.1 there is more than 1 path between any 2 nodes apart from $(s,y)$, so the graph is not a tree. ...

Comment: @curryage ... 3.2 $d(x,y) > d(u,v)$; this is impossible as $d(u,v) = diam(G)$ by assumption and a graph's diameter is the maximal minimum distance between any two nodes. in the case of a tree there is exactly 1 path between any 2 nodes, so the definition reduces to 'maximum distance between any two nodes'.

Comment: I don't see how the statement after "equivalent to" is equivalent to the preceding statement (after "3) and 4) imply") -- where did the $d(s, z_{xy})$ term on the LHS go?

Answer (score 14):

The intuition behind is very easy to understand. Suppose I have to find longest path that exists between any two nodes in the given tree.

After drawing some diagrams we can observe that the longest path will always occur between two leaf nodes( nodes having only one edge linked). 
This can also be proved by contradiction that if longest path is between two nodes and either or both of two nodes is not a leaf node then we can extend the path to get a longer path.

So one way is to first check what nodes are leaf nodes, then start BFS from one of the leaf node to get the node farthest from it.

Instead of first finding which nodes are leaf nodes , we start BFS from a random node and then see which node is farthest from it. Let the node farthest be x.  It is clear that x is a leaf node. Now if we start BFS from x and check farthest node from it, we will get our answer.

But what is the guarantee that x will be a end point of a maximum path?

Let's see by an example :-

```
       1   
    / /\ \
   6 2  4 8
         \ \
          5 9
           \
            7
```

Suppose I started my BFS from 6. The node at maximum distance from 6 is node 7. Using BFS we can get this node. Now we star BFS from node 7 to get node 9 at maximum distance. Path from node 7 to node 9 is clearly the longest path.

What if BFS that started from node 6 gave 2 as the node at maximum distance. Then when we will BFS from 2 we will get 7 as node at maximum distance and longest path will be then 2->1->4->5->7 with length 4. But the actual longest path length is 5. This cannot happen because BFS from node 6 will never give node 2 as node at maximum distance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thats a simple & clear explanation! thanks :)

Comment: this does not answer why the procedure will work in general.

Comment: "the longest path will always occur between two leaf nodes" -- this is trivially false for graphs that have no leaf nodes.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 3 and corrected answer**

There's an error in the linked solution set (see update 2 below), but it can be easily corrected with @Yuval Filmus's suggestion in the question's comment, which further allows us to rule out one of the possibilities mentioned in the solution set.

This proof hinges on two facts: one, that there is exactly one path between any two nodes in a binary tree; and two, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

Let $s$ be the root of the first BFS and let $u$ be the final vertex discovered (which means that $u$ must be the farthest point from $s$). Also, let $d(a,b)$ be a diameter. Clearly, $a$, $b$, and $u$ must all be leaves, since otherwise $d(a,b)$ wouldn't be a diameter, and $u$ wouldn't be discovered last (if any of the nodes had children, they would no longer be endpoints of paths of "maximal length", as you could just extend the path by exploring their children). Let $t$ be the lowest common ancestor of $a$ and $b$.

We claim that $t$ must be an ancestor of $u$. Suppose that it were not, then let $r$ be the lowest common ancestor of $u$ and $t$.

$d(u,s)=d(u,r)+d(r,s)$, so we have $d(u,s) \geq d(u,r)$.

Since $u$ was discovered last, $d(u,s) \geq d(a,s)$. Since $d(a,s)=d(a,r)+d(r,s)$, and $d(u,s)=d(u,r)+d(r,s)$, therefore, $d(u,r) \geq d(a,r)$.

Since $r$ is an ancestor of $t$, and $r \neq t$ (since $t$ is not an ancestor of $u$, yet $r$ is), $d(t,r) \geq 1$. Since $d(a,r)=d(a,t)+d(t,r)$, $d(a,r) > d(a,t)$.

Thus, since $d(u,r) > d(a,t)$, $d(u,r) + d(r,t) + d(t,b) > d(a,t) + d(t,b)$
$\to d(u,b) > d(a,b)$, contradicting the fact that $d(a,b)$ is a diameter (since diameters are supposed to be paths of maximal length).

Hence, $t$ is an ancestor of $u$.

Since $u$ was discovered last, $d(s,u) \geq d(s,a)$. Since $d(s,u)=d(s,t)+d(t,u)$, and $d(s,a)=d(s,t)+d(t,a)$, $d(t,u) \geq d(t,a)$. Since $d(t,u) \geq d(t,a)$, $d(b,t)+d(t,u) \geq d(b,t)+d(t,a) \to d(b,u) \geq d(b,a)$.

Since $d(a,b)$ is a diameter, $d(b,a) \geq d(b,u)$.

Therefore, since $d(b,u) \geq d(b,a)$ and $d(b,u) \leq d(b,a)$, $d(u,b) = d(a,b)$.

Therefore, $u$ is the endpoint of *some* diameter, and thus the second BFS works (the longest path from an endpoint of a diameter must be a diameter).

**Update 2**

Note that [the linked solution set](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/fall01/handouts/ps9sol.pdf) contains an error:

> If the paths $p_1$ from $s$ to $u$ and $p_2$ from $a$ to $b$ do not share edges, then the path from $t$ to $u$ includes $s$.

Consider the following counterexample: suppose $s$ is the root of the first BFS tree, and $t$ is the lowest common ancestor of leaves $a$, $u$, and $b$. No edges are shared; only the vertex $t$ is shared. Let $d(a,t) = d(b,t) = d(u,t) = 2$, and let $d(s,t)=1$. Finally, suppose $u$ is discovered last in the BFS. Then $d(a,b)$ is a diameter, $t$ is the first node discovered on that path, and the path from $t$ to $u$ does *not* include $s$.

To fix this, it's probably necessary to change "do not share edges" to "do not share vertices, as suggested by @Yuval Filmus.

**Update**

As @j_random_hacker points out in the comments, Lemma 1 below is not sufficient to show that $u$ is an endpoint of some diameter. Hence, the below proof is incomplete.

**Original incorrect answer**

Suppose we have $d(a, b)$ being a diameter, but we don't know which vertices $a$ and $b$ are, so we start a BFS from some vertex $s$.

If $s = a$, then the first BFS would yield either $b$ or some node $b'$ equally distant from $a$, and the second would either go back to $a$ or to some equally distant node $a'$, and the scheme obviously works. Similarly, if $s = b$, then two BFS would work for the same reason.

Otherwise, we have $s \neq a, b$.

**Lemma 0**: Both $a$ and $b$ are leaf nodes in the tree rooted at $s$.

**Proof 0**: If they weren't leaf nodes, we could increase $d(a,b)$ by extending the endpoints to leaf nodes, contradicting $d(a, b)$ being a diameter.

**Lemma 1**: At least one of $d(s,a)$ and $d(s, b)$ is the largest possible value of $d(s,u)$ for all $u$.

**Proof 1**: Suppose we have a $u$ that violates the lemma. $u$ cannot be a descendent of $a$ or $b$ since they are leaves from Lemma 0, and $u$ cannot be an ancestor, since that would make it *closer* to $s$, and it would no longer be able to violate the lemma. Let $t$ be the lowest common ancestor of $a$ and $b$. If $t = s$, then both $d(a, u)$ and $d(b, u)$ would be greater than $d(a, b)$, a contradiction. Otherwise, $t \neq s$ and either $u$ is a descendant of $t$, or not.

If $u$ is a descendant of $t$, then since $d(s,u)$ is greater than both $d(s, a)$ and $d(s, b)$, we have $d(t,u)$ is greater than both $d(t, a)$ and $d(t, b)$ and thus $d(a, u)$ and $d(b,u)$ are both greater than $d(a,b)$, a contradiction since $d(a,b)$ is a diameter.

If $u$ is not a descendant of $t$, then let $w$ be the unique ancestor of $u$ such that $d(s,t) = d(s,w)$. We know $w$ exists because $d(s,t) < d(s,u)$. Then, we have $d(t, b) < d(w,u) < d(t,w) + d(w,u) = d(t,u)$ and thus $d(a, u) = d(a, t) + d(t, u) > d(a, t) + d(t, b) = d(a, b)$, again contradicting $d(a, b)$ being a diameter.

**Main result**: Starting from any root $s$ and performing a BFS will result in some $a$ being discovered last. Using that $a$ as the root of a second $BFS$ will result in $b$ being discovered last, with $d(a,b)$ guaranteed to be a diameter.

**proof**: From lemma 1, the first BFS will find an $a$ that is furthest from $s$, which is guaranteed to be one of the endpoints of a diameter. The second BFS will find that diameter, since in a tree there's exactly one simple path between any two nodes.

Comment: Looks good, but I think the claim "then $d(t,u) > d(t,b)$" needs spelling out. Setting $v=LCA(t,u)$, we have $d(s,u)=d(s,v)+d(v,u) > d(s,v)+d(v,b)$ by the assumption on $u$, so $d(v,u) > d(v,b)$. Also $d(t,v)+d(v,b) = 2d(t,v)+d(t,b) \ge d(t,b)$ since the path $t-v$ needs to be traversed up and then back down. Thus $d(t,u) = d(t,v)+d(v,u) > d(t,v)+d(v,b) \ge d(t,b)$.

Comment: In this part of the proof, you're explicitly assuming (with the words "If the latter") that $u$ is not a descendant of $t$, meaning the path $s-u$ does not go through $t$ (or did you mean something else by "both paths"?) Also I'm thinking that Lemma 1 doesn't actually establish that the BFS started from $s$ finds an endpoint of a diameter -- this is only established in the case that there is a *unique* vertex having maximal distance from $s$. Also (sorry to pile on...) it doesn't look like Lemma 0 is actually used anywhere?

Comment: Ah good point; I was mistaken. I edited my answer to mention the usage of Lemma 0, and will look at the other point here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I just changed the paragraph above "main result". Can you take another look?

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't think the statement of Lemma 1 is enough to establish that the BFS finds the endpoint of some diameter. You need to show that every vertex at maximum distance from $s$ is the endpoint of some diameter, but currently you only show that an endpoint of some diameter (or, interpreting $a-b$ to be any diameter, every diameter) is at maximum distance from $s$. It could be that the vertex at maximum distance from $s$ found by the BFS is not the endpoint of any diameter. (Unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: Call a vertex "good" if it's the endpoint of some diameter, and "bad" otherwise. There is a bucket containing all vertices at maximum distance from $s$; the BFS chooses a vertex from this bucket. What you have proven so far is that there is at least one "good" vertex in the bucket (since there is clearly at least one diameter in a finite tree). This means the BFS has a chance to work (and that it it is guaranteed to work if the bucket contains only one vertex) -- but for it to be guaranteed to work on larger buckets, you need to show that there are no "bad" vertices in the bucket.

Comment: good point, I think this solution may be wrong. I'll do a rewrite shortly.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I wrote another answer based on the original MIT solution set in the question (which seems to be highly flawed). I think this one should be correct, let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Looks good to me now! Agree that there is an error in the solution set -- though even after changing "edges" to "vertices" it makes no sense (your proof shows the premise is then in fact false, so anything at all could be written after "then").

Comment: Nicely and concisely explained. Thank you so much !

Comment: In the update2, can `t` be the first node discovered on the path from `a` to `b`. Given that `d(a, t) = d(b, t) = 2` and `t` is the lowest common ancestor of `a` and `b`, then `t` should not be the first node discovered in the path from `a` to `b`. In fact, it should be the second node. However, overall the answer was very helpful. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

It works because-

1. For any randomly chosen vertex $u$, the farthest vertex from it lies on one end of the diameter.
2. If vertex $a$ is one end of the diameter, the farthest vertex from it is the other end.

The first BFS takes you to one end of the diameter and the second BFS from that end takes you to the other end.

**Proof**

**#2** is easy to see why it's true. We will see why **#1** is true by contradiction. Let's suppose, the path from vertex $a$ to $b$ is the diameter of the tree and $v$, which is not on the diameter, is the farthest vertex from $u$. Also, let's assume paths $(a,b)$ and $(u,v)$ cross over at $t$ ($t$ can more generally be a path with multiple vertices). Because we don't have any cycles, all paths between vertices $a$, $b$, $u$ and $v$ pass through $t$.

[image]

1. By our assumptions $d(a,b)$ is the diameter and $d(u,v)$ is larger than both $d(u,a)$ and $d(u,b)$.
2. Path $(u,t)$ is the common piece in all paths originating from $u$ and hence we can deduce that $d(v, t) > d(a, t)$ ($v$ is farther away from $t$ as compared to $a$).
3. This implies that $v$ is also farther away from $b$ as compared to $a$ and $d(v,b) > d(a,b)$. *(add $d(t,b)$ to both sides in previous step)*
4. This contradicts our initial assumption that $(a,b)$ is a diameter because we have found a path $(v,b)$ which is longer. Symmetrically, we can also see why $d(v,a) > d(a,b)$.
5. Hence, the farthest vertex from $u$ must either be $a$ or $b$ if $(a,b)$ is indeed the diameter.

Comment: What does this add over https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/68224/755?  It seems like the same answer, with the same shortcomings.  I think you need to explain why the statement marked 1. is always true.  As [I previously explained](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work#comment145469_68224), it is not obvious, and isn't true for general graphs, so it needs some justification.

Comment: On second look, not much actually apart from being slightly more concise. I will try and add justifications for both. Also, the question was asked for trees so I don't think we should worry about general graphs at least in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is equivalent to claiming that every deepest leaf in a tree rooted at $s$ is an endpoint to a diameter.

Suppose $p$ is an arbitrary path with end points $(a,b)$, and that $d$ is some leaf that is one of the deepest.  Let $x$ be the deepest common ancestor of $a$ and $b$.

Here is how to construct a path ending in $d$ that it at least as long as path $p$, assuming WLOG $\text{depth}(a) \ge \text{depth}(b)$:

```
   x 
  / \       (b,d) is at least as long
 / \ \
a   d b

   x 
  / \       (a,d) is at least as long
 / / \
a d   b

   /\ 
  x  \      (a,d) is at least as long
 / \  \
a   b  d
```

Therefore a diameter can be constructed for every vertex $d$ from any other diameter.

(Edited: the previous proof only established that every diameter ended in a deepest vertex, not that every deepest vertex was part of a diameter, embarrassing mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of BFS, the distance (from the starting node) of each node explored is either equal to the distance of the previous node explored or greater by 1. Thus, the last node explored by BFS will be among those farthest from the starting node.

Thus, the algorithm of using BFS twice amounts to "Pick an arbitrary node $x$. Find the node $a$ farthest from $x$ (last node found by BFS starting from $x$). Find the node $b$ farthest from $a$ (last node found by BFS starting from $a$).", which thus finds two nodes of maximum distance from eachother.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with the intuition.  However, the "thus" in the your last sentence is not obvious.  Why does that follow?  Why does the node farthest from $x$ have to be one of the two nodes at maximum distance from each other?  It seems like that needs some proof.

Comment: I'm not sure how to construct such a proof. I feel like the converse is intuitively true: if two nodes are at maximum distance from each other, then, for any given node, one of the two is at the greatest possible distance from it.

Comment: The "intuitively true" claim isn't true in general for general graphs.  See the graph in http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/213/755, and imagine starting the BFS from node $v$ (i.e., let $x=v$); then it will pick $a=u$ and find the node $b$ at greatest distance from $a$, but that doesn't find the two nodes of maximum distance from each other.  So the claimed statement, if true, must rely on some special property of trees that doesn't hold for general graphs.

Comment: Yes, but this question specifies undirected trees, which is the context I'm intuiting in. Barring cycles and directed edges makes many graph problems significantly simpler to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

One key thing to know is that a tree is always planar, which means it can be laid out on a plane, so often ordinary 2-dimensional thinking works. In this case, the algorithm says starting anywhere, go as far away as you can. The distance from that point to as far as you can get away from that point is the longest distance in the tree, and therefore the diameter.

This method would also work to find the diameter of a real, physical island if we defined that as the diameter of the smallest circle that would fully enclose the island.

Answer (score 0):

@op, the way the cases are defined in the PDF may be a bit off.

I think that the two cases should be:

1. $p_1$ does not intersect with $p_2$, i.e. there are no common vertices between paths $p_1$ and $p_2$.  In this case, define $t$ as the first node on $p_2$ discovered by the first BFS starting at $s$.
2. $p_1$ and $p_2$ have at least one common vertex.  In this case, define $t$ to be the first node on $p_2$ discovered by the first BFS that is also on $p_1$.

The rest of the proof in the PDF should follow.

With this definition, the figure shown by OP falls into Case 2.

Answer (score -1):

First run a DFS from a random node then the diameter of a tree is the path between the deepest leaves of a node in its DFS subtree:
[image]

Comment: Why does this work?