# Print Binary Tree Diameter Path

Tags: binary-trees, recursion

Diameter of the tree is defined as a long path or route, between any two nodes in a tree. The path may or may not goes through the ROOT.

Print the Longest leaf to leaf path in a binary tree and its length

I worth an algorithm that calculates the diameter in Swift:

```
func diameter() -> Int {
 return diameterHelper(root).Diameter
}

typealias HeightAndDiameter = (Height: Int, Diameter: Int)

private func diameterHelper(node: TreeNode<T>?) -> HeightAndDiameter {

   guard let node = node else {
     return HeightAndDiameter(Height:0, Diameter:0)
   }

   let left  = diameterHelper(node.left)
   let right = diameterHelper(node.right)

   let height   = max(left.Height, right.Height) + 1
   let diameter = max(left.Height + right.Height + 1, max(left.Diameter, right.Diameter))

   return HeightAndDiameter(Height: height, Diameter: diameter)
}
```

I have tried to adapt this algorithm, but it doesn't work for all the cases.

```
  func diameterPath() -> [T] {
    return diameterPathHelper(root).Path
  }

  typealias HeightAndDiameterAndPath = (Height: Int, Diameter: Int, Path: [T])

  private func diameterPathHelper(node: TreeNode<T>?) -> HeightAndDiameterAndPath {

    guard let node = node else {
      return HeightAndDiameterAndPath(0, 0, [])
    }

    let left  = diameterPathHelper(node.left)
    let right = diameterPathHelper(node.right)

    let height = max(left.Height, right.Height) + 1

    if left.Height + right.Height + 1 > max(left.Diameter, right.Diameter) {
      let currentDiameter = left.Height + right.Height + 1
      let path = left.Path + [node.data] + right.Path
      return HeightAndDiameterAndPath(height, currentDiameter, path)

    } else {
      if left.Diameter > right.Diameter {
        return HeightAndDiameterAndPath(height, left.Diameter, left.Path)
      } else {
        return HeightAndDiameterAndPath(height, right.Diameter, right.Path)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please replace the code with pseudocode. Your code is hard to read.

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22855/755.  And for the future: note that coding questions are off-topic here, and not everyone knows Swift; we want you to avoid code and instead present ideas, pseudocode, and proofs.

Answer (score 0):

One natural approach goes as follows. Compute recursively for each node both the longest leaf-to-leaf path in the subtree rooted at the node, and the depth of the deepest leaf. From this information for the two children of a node you can compute the same information for the node itself. Once you have reached the root, you have obtained your answer.

The above only computes the *length* of the longest path, but you can actually extract the longest path itself from the data for each node. Details left to you.