# Algorithm and Formalism for Most Remote Vertices

Tags: graphs

In the graph below, **N** and **M** are most remote, and **H** is also an extremum.

[image: An example graph]

Has the problem of finding the most remote vertices been formalized? Could you point me to publications or references on the subject? Does an algorithm exist for finding the most remote edges of a graph?

Please note that I am not asking you to invent an algorithm, but I'm asking for information.

Comment: "Has this problem been formalized?" What problem?

Comment: Please change "most remote edges" to "most remote vertices" in the title and in the body. Although there is a way to define "the most remote edges" to be subtly different from "the most remote vertices". However, I do not think that is your intention according to the given example.

Comment: This sounds like the *diameter* of a graph, which is the maximum distance between two vertices. Finding the diameter of a graph is a well-known problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The diameter will only point to **H** and **M**, but I also want to find **N**.

Comment: @MrMartin. No, the diameter are $N$ and $M$, the distance between which is 9. There is no diameter that contains $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to formulate your problem is well known as **finding the diameter of a graph** as the following description in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)).

> The diameter $d$ d of a graph is the maximum eccentricity of any vertex in the graph. That is, $d$ is the greatest distance between any pair of vertices or, alternatively, $d=\max_{v\in V}\epsilon (v)$. To find the diameter of a graph, first find [the shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) between each pair of vertices. The greatest length of any of these paths is the diameter of the graph.
>
> A peripheral vertex in a graph of diameter $d$ is one that is distance $d$ from some other vertex—that is, a vertex that achieves the diameter. Formally, $v$ is peripheral if $\epsilon (v)=d$.

Similarly to the way we talk about the diameter of a circle, the term "diameter of a graph" is overloaded. It can also mean, although less frequently, any shortest path between any two vertices whose length is equal to the maximum eccentricity.

**If the graph is a tree, there is an algorithm that finds its diameter using only two BFS scans**. Choose an arbitrary vertex $v$. Do a breadth first search from $v$ that  finds a vertex that is farthest away from $v$. Call the vertex $u$. Do another BFS from $u$ that finds a vertex that is farthest away from $u$. Call the vertex $u'$. The distance between $u$ and $u'$ is the diameter of the graph.

**In a general graph, many algorithms can be used to to find the diameter of a graph**. Please check [this CS StackExchange question and answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/194/the-time-complexity-of-finding-the-diameter-of-a-graph), where most algorithms are in fact designed to solve the all-pairs-shortest-path problem.

In the example graph given in the question, the distance between $N$ and $M$, 9, is the diameter. In fact, $N$ and $M$ are the only two peripheral vertices in that graph. (OP calls peripheral vertices as most remote). However, $H$ is not a peripheral vertex, since the furthest distance from any vertex to $H$ is only 8. ($H$ is not a pseudo-peripheral vertex, either.)

We could **define an extremum of a graph as a vertex whose eccentricity is not smaller than the eccentricity of any of its neighbors**. We could also **define a strong extremum of a graph as a vertex whose distance to any vertex $v$ is not smaller than the distance from any of its neighbors to $v$**. Every peripheral vertices is an extremum and every strong extremum is an extremum. We can recall [a leaf vertex of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) means a vertex of degree 1. Every leaf is a strong extremum. Note that **$H$ is a leaf**. All those algorithms that compute all-pairs-shortest-paths can be adapted easily to find all (strong) extremum vertices as well. A simple degree-counting algorithm will find all leaves of a graph. (Please note this definition of "extremum" might not be standard at all. As far as I have tried, I have not found a single article that defines that concept. Well, I can only check probably a negligible number of articles among a myriad of them. There is probably some existing term for it in papers about social network.)

Comment: Right, the diameter will give me the pair of most remote edges from each other, but not all extrema. What if I'm also interested in finding **H**?

Comment: You want to find all vertices of maximum eccentricity.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I am afraid that you have been misled by the example graph since $H$ does not have maximum eccentricity, although it looks like $H$ does.

Comment: If the graph is a cycle, all nodes are on a diameter, but none of them is an extreme. Regarding degree-counting, if **H** were to connect to itself it would have higher degree than **L** or **C**.

Comment: The biggest factor here is that you have not defined what is an "extremum" and there is no standard definition to that term. I have not found even one definition of that term applied to graph theory. So, per your request, I decided to settle down on one of my many choices.

Comment: The simplest interpretation of your "extremum" might be "a leaf vertex". I have also mentioned a few other choices, such as "peripheral", "pseudo-peripheral" and etc. Finally I set on one that sounds more interesting and not as trivial as "a leaf vertex". Can you give a definition what you meant by "extremum"? Or describe what kind of properties should an "extremum" have? (Now I have fully realized that I should have asked for your clarification before jumping to my preferences.) In a hindsight, "a leaf vertex", simple and convincing, might be the best choice here.

Comment: By the way, I was fully aware of the fact all nodes on a cycle graph are peripherals. It make sense to say every node on a cycle graph is an "extremum" (more or less as every point in a constant function is a maximum and a minimum) . On the other hand, I can understand if that statement does not make much sense to you, either according to your example graph or your intention.

Comment: In general, we avoid including graphs with loops in discussions, textbooks and papers. Why? Because in most of the situations, it is just a distraction to the essence of the problem. So I do not want to consider the case when "$H$ were to connect to itself" (at least initially for the sake of a speedy discussion), which might be a trivial counterexample to degree-counting.  Suppose we do take graph with loops out of consideration. Does the situation become clearer?